# Unable to import owlready2 modules: Got 'sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: sqlite_schema' error with ' from owlready2 import * '

Tags: python, owlready

I got the below error when I run this line, `from owlready2 import *`

```
(onto) C:\FYP\Onto>py testonto.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testonto.py", line 2, in <module>
    from owlready2 import *
  File "C:\FYP\Onto\onto\lib\site-packages\owlready2\__init__.py", line 129, in <module>
    default_world = IRIS = World()
  File "C:\FYP\Onto\onto\lib\site-packages\owlready2\namespace.py", line 443, in __init__
    self.set_backend(backend, filename, dbname, **kargs)
  File "C:\FYP\Onto\onto\lib\site-packages\owlready2\namespace.py", line 453, in set_backend
    self.graph = Graph(filename, world = self, **kargs)
  File "C:\FYP\Onto\onto\lib\site-packages\owlready2\triplelite.py", line 173, in __init__
    self.analyze()
  File "C:\FYP\Onto\onto\lib\site-packages\owlready2\triplelite.py", line 403, in analyze
    self.execute("""ANALYZE sqlite_schema""")
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: sqlite_schema
```

python version 3.8.3
Any solution? Thank you in advance

Comment: Try `sqlite_master` instead: https://www.sqlite.org/schematab.html#alternative_names

Answer (score 0):

Does upgrading your sqlite version to `3.33.0` help?